# VSCODE Status Bar Color Is Fixed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCODE 1.46.1.

The color (purple) in the status bar is fixed. It is not changing no matter how much I change the theme.

To make sure it is not caused by any extension, I have disabled all extensions.

To make sure it is not caused by any settings, I have removed everything from the `settings.json` file except the following lines:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+"
}
```

Still the taskbar looks the following.

[image]

What might be the issue here?

Comment: do you have any `workbench.colorCustomizations {}` entry in your `settings.json`?

Comment: I have deleted .vscode directory. uninstalled and reinstalled vscode. The only settings I have in `settings.json` is in the question. Which is `"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+"`

Comment: I have uninstalled vscode. deleted both `~/.config/Code` & `~/.vscode`. Then reinstalled vscode. No improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        // Status bar when a folder or workspace is active
        "statusBar.background": "#ff0000",
        "statusBar.foreground": "#ff0000",
        "statusBar.border": "#ffff00",

        // Status bar when VSCode is in debugging mode
        "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#ffffff",
        "statusBar.debuggingForeground": "#000000",
        "statusBar.debuggingBorder": "#ff0000",

        // Status bar when no folder or workspace has been opened. 
        "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#ff0000",
        "statusBar.noFolderBorder": "#0000ff",
        "statusBar.noFolderForeground": "#00ff00"
    }
}
```

If you want to change the status bar when you've got no folders open, you can use

`"statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#ffffff"`

these are the settings that change your status bar colors. Verify if you have any added to your `settings.json` or in any workspace file or a `settings.json` in your `.vscode` folder.

Comment: I have deleted .vscode directory. uninstalled and reinstalled vscode. Added your setting to check if the color change. The color is not changing.

Comment: can you delete all  the files in your `%AppData%\Code`  and the `%UserProfile%\.vscode` folder and check, and also there is another setting added to the ans

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 19.3. I have deleted `~/.vscode`. What is the `%AppData%\Code` equivalent in Linux?

Comment: I have also removed `~/.config/Code` and reinstalled, not working.

Comment: Is purple the default status bar color for Light & Light+. The status color is changing for other themes.

Comment: OMG YES it is! It will change when you start a debug session,  but YES :)

Comment: I added all the states the status bar will be, the one where you haven't opened any folder or a git repo or a workspace (the last 3 settings) you can use to configure when nothing has been opened

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after I installed and uninstalled a color extension. I tried to modify the settings.json file to no avail. I found that my problem was that the extension had modified the *.code-workspace file and added these lines

```
"settings": {
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "activityBar.background": "#312F07",
  "titleBar.activeBackground": "#444209",
  "titleBar.activeForeground": "#FCFBE9"
}
```

}

This configuration was overriding the rest. The solution was simply to remove them from every workspace file, which allowed the activity bar color to be back to its normal behavior (clear color for light themes and viceversa).